# "Bad command or file name" error when compiling with g++ using Make

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, mingw, mingw32

I recently installed MinGW and learnt how to use Make. But I get an error whenever I try to compile a CPP source file using make. Below is the output:

```
MAKE Version 3.6  Copyright (c) 1991 Borland International

Available memory 33397872 bytes

        mingw32-g++ main.cpp --std=c++11 -o program
Bad command or file name
```

The main.cpp is a very simple "Hello World" type program. The command works when I use it in the Command Prompt directly.
I am running Windows 8.1 with MinGW. GCC version 4.8

Comment: Is the directory for the MinGw binaries in your `PATH` environment variable? Also usually it should be just `g++`.

Comment: Yes, the binaries are in my path variable. Both mingw32-g++ and g++  get the job done. The former is the MinGW version.

Comment: You haven't posted the makefile. You've posted the output of the failing make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another respondent has noted, you should not be trying to coax Borland's antique `make` into working with MinGW; the most appropriate option for you would be either `mingw32-make`, (a native windows build of GNU `make` suitable for use directly from a `cmd.exe` shell session), or install MinGW.org's MSYS, and use the `make` which it provides; either of these may be installed using MinGW.org's `mingw-get` installation manager.

Either of these options should work for you, while avoiding the bloat of Cygwin, (or the equally bloated MSYS2, which should not be confused with the MinGW.org MSYS product). Do note that, if you choose the MSYS option, you will be installing a very light-weight fork of an old, but still perfectly adequate and capable, version of Cygwin.

In closing, to clear up your evident confusion, I would also point out that the `g++.exe` which you find in the `$MINGW32_ROOT/bin` directory, and the `mingw32-g++.exe` to which you refer, are one and the same -- **both** are the MinGW compiler, and you would normally invoke it simply as `g++`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Only now I realized that make and mingw32-make weren't the same command. I had also installed Turbo C++ for research purposes and added its folder to my PATH variable. After reading your answer, I changed my command. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like to learn [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), not Borland one from 1991.

Make sure you installed GNU make package in Cygwin. Check that it is present by typing in the bash command line:

```
$ type -a make
```

It should respond with something like:

```
/usr/bin/make
/bin/make
```

And then:

```
$ make --version
```

Which should respond with something like:

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Is there any way I could get that version on MinGW? I don't want to download Cygwin.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with MinGW. The command works when I enter it into the Command Prompt directly.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32599927/841108) answer. You could compile GNU make 4.x from its source code.