# Error in makefile ("no input files")

Tags: c, makefile, g++, gnu-make

This is my absolute first time ever making a makefile, and I'm really trying to understand the process.

I'm trying to create a very simple makefile for a C++ project whose structure is as follows:

**root folder**
    makefile
    readme
**src folder**
    *...source files all here...*
**include folder**
    *...header files for external libraries here...*
**lib folder**
    *...external lib files all here...*
**bin folder**
    *...output directory for built executable...*
    **obj folder**
    *...object files all here...*

I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).

Here's my makefile:

```
IDIR=include .
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)
ODIR=bin/obj
LDIR=lib
LIBS=none
SRC=src


_DEPS=hello.h
DEPS=$(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/,%(_DEPS))
_OBJ=file1.o file2.o
OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) # $(LIBS)

test_proj: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

When I run `make` on this, I get the following error:

```
g++      -o .o
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target '.o' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [.o] Error 1
```

I'm using GNU Make 3.82.90 built for i686-pc-mingw32, if that matters at all.

Can anyone point out whatever ridiculous error I'm making?

Comment: Why such a complex file tree structure for a small project?

Comment: Honestly, I agree it's overkill and I've scaled this down to a working and simpler makefile. Part of my goal with this project was to decouple myself for Windows / Visual Studio and gain confidence in the GNU toolchain and workflow. The project will likely grow, but I wanted to make sure I could build a makefile that would work on a project with a more complicated structure, so I started with this for my simple project. So yeah, overkill :)

Comment: Your overall goal might be satisfied by switching to Linux and develop under Linux.

Comment: Working on it :) Working on Windows = a temporary condition; I just really wanted to get started on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IDIR=include .
```

is the first problem. Replace it by:

```
IDIR=include
```

With your code `CFLAGS` is expanded as:

```
-Iinclude .
```

It does not make sense, I'm afraid. The second problem is:

```
DEPS=$(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/,%(_DEPS))
```

which should probably be:

```
DEPS=$(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
```

and would expand as:

```
DEPS=include/hello.h
```

if you fix the first problem, else as:

```
DEPS=include ./hello.h
```

which does not make sense neither. The cumulated effect of these two errors are strange recipes (I didn't try to expand them by hand) that probably trigger a make implicit rule with wrong parameters.

Comment: A million eye skims missed this one: DEPS=$(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/,%(_DEPS))

Thanks a million sir

Answer (score 1):

```
IDIR=include .
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)
```

This is wrong. First, for C++ code, use `CXX` not `CC` and `CXXFLAGS` not `CFLAGS`. Run `make -p`  to understand the builtin rules of your `make`.

Then `-I$(IDIR)` does not "distribute" the `-I`, and `IDIR` is never used elsewhere. So I suggest to start your `Makefile` with:

```
CXX=g++
MY_CXX_LANG_FLAGS= -std=c++11
MY_CXX_WARN_FLAGS= -Wall -Wextra
MY_CXX_INCL_FLAGS= -I.  -Iinclude
MY_CXX_MACRO_FLAGS= -DMYFOO=32
### replace with -O2 for a release build below
MY_CXX_OPTIM_FLAGS= -g 
CXXFLAGS= $(MY_CXX_LANG_FLAGS) $(MY_CXX_WARN_FLAGS) \
          $(MY_CXX_INCL_FLAGS) $(MY_CXX_MACRO_FLAGS)
```

I won't improve your `Makefile`, but I do suggest to upgrade to GNU `make` version 4 if possible (and compiling `make` 4.1 from its [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/) code is worthwhile in 2015) for that purpose. If possible enable GUILE scripting in it.

If you are forced to use `make` 3.82 debug your `Makefile` using [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (with `-x`); if you can afford a `make` version 4 use its `--trace` option

BTW, you might consider using automatic dependencies, that is generating dependencies by passing [`-M` or `-MG` (etc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) flags of `g++`, see [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31488442/841108).

At last, a *simple* project for a small program (less than a hundred thousands of source lines) might just put all (a few dozens of) its files in the current directory (then the `Makefile`  could be simpler); your proposed directory structure might be arcane for a *simple* project (but could worth the pain if you have millions of C++ source lines of code). I've given several *simple* examples of `Makefile`, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108). And GNU make source code itself has a less complex file tree that what you want.

BTW, I strongly disagree with the opinions of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599191/841108) answer (which I did upvote, since it is helpful). I don't feel that GNU make is senile, but I regret that, instead of using recent features available on recent versions (4.x) of `make`, many people prefer to use complex and arcane `Makefile` generators (like `cmake`) instead of coding a clever `Makefile` (for `make` version 4 specifically).

At last, you could use other builders, e.g. [omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html), `icmake`, ....